# Powershell scripts don't work by default

Tags: windows, powershell

So I wanted to get started with writing a powershell script. I wanted to start small and simply write a script that substiutes a local file folder as a drive. Pretty simple. I've done it before using the old DOS command tools.

So the script I wanted to write is:

```
subst d: G:\CER
```

Ok, so I try to execute the script in the Powershell ISE by pressing the 'Play' button (i.e. F5)

So what do I get?

> File G:\CER\Make_Stage.ps1 cannot be
>   loaded because the **execution of
>   scripts is disabled** on this system.
>   Please  see "get-help about_signing"
>   for more details. At line:0 char:0

How stupid is this, that out of the box execution of powershell scripts are ***disabled***! i.e. By default! Simply incredible that by default this new tool simply does **not** work.
Powershell has to be the stupidest scripting shell out there.

So apparently I have to register something somewhere (hopefully not with MS). If anyone has an answer as to how to fix this, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To enable scripting, open a powershell prompt as Administrator and run:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Here's a blog post from Lee that talks about PowerShell's security principles (http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2005/08/16/demonstration-of-monads-security-features/).

Keep in mind that most computer will never run a PowerShell script.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That's precisely what I needed.

Comment: Although, actually, "most computers will never" isn't true. Microsoft is using PowerShell in their "Fix It" stuff, but you can override ExecutionPolicy on the PowerShell.exe command-line to get around it without changing the setting.

Comment: Also: if you're not the administrator, you can still: Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser

Comment: @Jaykul: is this what "Fix it" doing?

Comment: @zespri: I haven't specifically check how they're doing it, but they're either calling PowerShell with a -ExecutionPolicy parameter, or they have their own custom host (unlikely)...

Comment: so why do they ship with powershell installed?

Answer (score 5):

To fix this, execute:

```
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
```

In an elevated PowerShell prompt.

Answer (score -2):

Found it:

From the help docs (deeep in the help docs)

> LONG DESCRIPTION
>       The Restricted execution policy does not permit any scripts to run.

A long article ensues on how to set an execution policy. I'm not impressed so far with PS.